# Godaddy .htaccess and mod_url

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, godaddy

I'm an experienced full stack developer and freshly minted webmaster.  Recently my client asked me to create a redirect from one url to an outside page.  I know how to make a page redirect and I'm pretty sure doing it requires me to work on the .htaccess file or mod_url or both.

The site is hosted at Godaddy on the "Economy Web Hosting Linux" plan.  The UI is not very friendly. It's an Apache server.  What I need to know is where do I find the .htaccess file to edit it?  I also probably need to know where to find the mod_url settings.  I can probably do the needful from there.

Comment: If you don't have the necessary mods, you could use a simple PHP script in index.php of the relevant directory to accomplish this: <?php header('location: http://othersite/path'); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Unless an `.htaccess` file has been created before, you'll just need to create one in a relevant directory - for example, if you want a redirect from `/foo/bar.html` you can put the `.htaccess` file in the web root (`/`) or in the `/foo` directory.

From there, you'll just want to use `mod_alias` for a simple redirect:

```
Redirect /foo/bar.html http://example.com/outside/page
```

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but I think it may work.